# Automatic library version update for Gradle projects is currently unsupported. Please update your build.gradle manually

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have this in my building.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.2-4'
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.2'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

}
```

and always show me this

```
Outdated Kotlin Runtime
        Your version of Kotlin runtime in 'kotlin-stdlib-1.1.2' library is 1.1.2, while plugin version is 1.1.2-release-Studio2.3-5.
        Runtime library should be updated to avoid compatibility problems.
```

[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Update the Kotlin version to 1.1.2-5:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.2-5'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

}
```

Comment: Whatever mentioned is outdated

Comment: current version is 1.2.51

Answer (score 0):

Consider using this gradle plugin

https://github.com/ben-manes/gradle-versions-plugin

It will tell you which libraries have updates available.